# Adding Exchange Multi Tenant to an existing Exchange Network

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email-server

I currently have an Exchange 2010 SP1 server in house, and due to some changes, it looks like i will need Multi Tenant support for a few extra domain names. Looking at the documentation i have found so far, it only mentions multi tenant support when upgrading from 2010 RTM -> SP1, and not what you do if you have already got 2010 SP1 installed.

So, from what i can gather, i have a few options:

- Install a new Exchange server with Multi Tenant support and migrate DBs over
- Back everything up and start again
- Something else...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add Exchange 2010 in hosting mode to an existing organization. You will need to stand up a new forest and Exchange organization and migrate the user mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was hoping i wouldent need to do that, but i suppose if it has to be done, it has to be done...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need Multi-Tenant suuport or do you only need to add some additional domains to your Accepted Domains? Are these domains for different customers/users who need segregation or are these for your company alone and you're just adding some new domain names that the company has acquired?

Comment: i would ned segregation for these domains... accepted domains wont do the job... i have multiple domains, and there is the potential for multiple users on different domains. i tried using accepted, but it got awkward...